# Pandas read_csv does not convert numbers with thousands- and decimal-separators

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to read a csv file that has decimal values in the format '1,234.56'.

My current code looks like this:

```
filepath = 'original_data'
filename = 'Real_Verbrauch_DE_201501010000_202303042359_Viertelstunde.csv'
dateparse = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%d.%m.%Y')
csv_path = os.path.join(filepath, filename)

df_original = pd.read_csv(
        csv_path, 
        sep = ';', 
        thousands = '.', 
        decimal = ',', 
        parse_dates = ['Datum'], 
        date_parser = dateparse, 
        dtype = {
            'Gesamt (Netzlast) [MWh] Originalauflösungen': float, 
            'Residuallast [MWh] Originalauflösungen': float,
            'Pumpspeicher [MWh] Originalauflösungen': float
        }
    )
```

With this code I get the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '11.118,75'
```

If I remove the dtype-parameter, the conversion works only for some values.

If possible, I would like to avoid a workaround, such as `replace('.','').replace(',','.')`, which would in turn introduce other problems.

Header and example of a row in the csv-file:

```
Datum;Anfang;Ende;Gesamt (Netzlast) [MWh] Originalauflösungen;Residuallast [MWh] Originalauflösungen;Pumpspeicher [MWh] Originalauflösungen
01.01.2015;00:00;00:15;11.210;9.051,75;123
10.04.2015;18:30;18:45;15.066,75;13.858,25;44,75
```

How should I adjust my code so that all values in the last three columns are converted to float type?

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine. Maybe you should update your version of Pandas?

Answer (score 0):

After running your code, everything works as expected. Maybe you have an older version of Pandas:

```
>>> df_original
       Datum Anfang   Ende  Gesamt (Netzlast) [MWh] Originalauflösungen  Residuallast [MWh] Originalauflösungen  Pumpspeicher [MWh] Originalauflösungen
0 2015-01-01  00:00  00:15                                     11210.00                                 9051.75                                  123.00
1 2015-04-10  18:30  18:45                                     15066.75                                13858.25                                   44.75

>>> df_original.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column                                       Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------                                       --------------  -----         
 0   Datum                                        2 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 1   Anfang                                       2 non-null      object        
 2   Ende                                         2 non-null      object        
 3   Gesamt (Netzlast) [MWh] Originalauflösungen  2 non-null      float64       
 4   Residuallast [MWh] Originalauflösungen       2 non-null      float64       
 5   Pumpspeicher [MWh] Originalauflösungen       2 non-null      float64       
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(3), object(2)
memory usage: 224.0+ bytes

>>> pd.__version__
'1.5.3'
```

Comment: Thanks for checking. I upgraded to the latest version and restarted the kernel but the error still appears. In my question above I added another example of a row in which the error actually appears.

Comment: @Lukas. And it works perfectly too. Maybe try to set the encoding `encoding='latin1'`,  `encoding='utf-8'`, etc